I have a problem with my minikube cluster where its supposed to be accessed via the browser
I have 4 yaml files that are fully configured on my local minikube cluster and are deployed that is running on a docker driver. Everything seems fine with my yaml files but when I run the minikube IP along with nodeport tcp = 192.168.49.2:31100 or alternatively when i run minikube service webapp-service --url
http://127.0.0.1:57963
They don't respond in my browser, can someone please help and give me feedback. Thanks in advance.
These are my yaml files below:
   mongo-config.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-config
data:
  mongo-url: mongo-service

    mongo-secret.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret
type: Opaque
data: 
  mongo-user: bW9uZ291c2Vy
  mongo-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==

    mongo.yaml

 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels: 
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:5.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
          requests: # <---- see indentation here
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017

   webapp.yaml

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels: 
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: nanajanashia/k8s-demo-app:v1.0
        resources:
          limits:
           memory: 512Mi
           cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: USER_NAME
          valueFrom: 
             secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: USER_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: DB_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config
              key: mongo-url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31100

